# How to remove use website option from the system.xml in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4

When we create system.xml file by default "use website" checkbox option will come. Is there any way to remove that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/etc/adminhtml/system.xml
>
> showInWebsite="0"

```
  <field id="test_name" translate="comment" sortOrder="51" type="text" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
    <label>Test Name</label>
  </field>
```

Comment: HI @Ravidrasinh Zala. Thanks for your respoonce. is there any way to remove [storeview] also

Answer (score 1):

set showInWebsite="0"
and as per your requirement set showInDefault="1" showInStore="0"